# Onsignal filtered notification by location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'm trying to send a notification using the location.
Following the onesignal documentation I came up with this:

```
 var notificationObj = {
    contents: {
    en: "asdasdasd"
  },
  include_player_ids: [playerId],
  send_after: "2017-02-9 19:17:00 GMT-0200",
  location: {
    radius: '10',
    lat: '-23.5404529',
    long: '-46.3616444'
 }
}
```

To test I'm using a fake location on android. Example: I placed a location on my smartphone 20 km from the coordinates defined in the locaton.

But it still does not work, am I letting something go?

Comment: You need to add in filters i guess however am facing a different problem in that though